# Dart code reformat didn't give me the expected format

Tags: dart, flutter, format

I have this code:

```dart
void main() {
  print('Hello!');
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Container(color: Colors.greenAccent)
    )
  );
}
```

When I reformat this code it becomes:

```dart
void main() {print('Hello!');runApp(MaterialApp(home:Container(color:Colors.greenAccent)));
}
```

I would like have:

```dart
void main() {
  print('Hello!');
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Container(color: Colors.greenAccent)
    )
  );
}
```

How can I reformat like that ?

Answer (score 2):

Add trailing commas like on this example: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/formatting

So your code would become:

```dart
void main() {
  print('Hello!');
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Container(color: Colors.greenAccent), , // <----- comma
    ), // <----- comma
  );
}
```